# Win 7 Login automatically logs me off after running CHKDSK

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, login, chkdsk

I'm currently running Win 7 Enterprise and I have 2 hard drives. I ran a CHKDSK on both drives. The process took about 7 hours to complete. Once it completed it brought me to the login-screen. I entered my password and then it seemed liked it was going to boot to my desktop, but then it automatically logged me out and redirected me back to the login-screen. (Same thing over and over) tried multiple times.

I was the only profile on the computer. I then tried to see if safe mode would work and it did.
I created a new user profile to see If I could login with the new user I just created and it worked.

My question is... Does anyone know how I can get my original user profile to login correctly?

I'm not computer illiterate, but far from an IT professional. 
I would really appreciate any help on this situation.

Comment: You don't.  The original profile is damaged.  I don't care if you have a 10TB drive it shouldn't take CHKDSK 7 hours to complete which means you likely had a near hardware failure

Comment: @Ramhound So would the best option be, Copy everything over to my new profile and back up all my files and replace my hard drives?

I have been noticing alot of clicking noises coming from the hard drive(s) or at least I think its the hard drive(s). Even as I'm write this to you, I can hear it click.

Comment: @Ramhound One other question. If the old profile is corrupt why can I still access the files from that profile from my new user profile? I'm glad the files are still there, but if my original profile is bad, I shouldn't be able to access the original profile and copy the files over to my new profile correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Because there are numerous files that are required to log into a profile your personal files isn't one of them